# Search/query the documentation programmatically

Tags: documentation

I wonder if it is feasible to query the documentation center for e.g build-in functions that contain a "Neat Examples"-section in their respective documentation page.

Another functionality that would be nice is a text base search that could, for instance, be used to find topics of interest in the documentation (e.g the history of UNIX distributions from the Application section of [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html))

Comment: You can [search "neat examples" on Google under site:reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Neat+Examples%22+site%3Areference.wolfram.com%2Flanguage%2Fref%2F&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WolframLanguageData` can be used for this.

```
Select[(Association@#)["NeatExamples"] > 0 &]@
  EntityValue[WolframLanguageData[], "DocumentationExampleCounts", 
   "EntityAssociation"] // Keys
```

I tried to do this with an implicit entity filtering on `"DocumentationExampleCounts"` but I could not get the filter to cooperate.  This would have used a smaller download.

Hope this helps.